# ROS Answers SE migration: map_server

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was just wondering if it is possible to use a map from lets say...Google Maps(?) and using waypoints to plan out a specific trail for the robot to follow? I am planning to use the SLAM technique so the robot can create its own map, but I also want it to follow specific waypoints that I input. Is this possible? How would I be able to achieve both? How would it work?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196745/map_server/) by [pikaboo](https://answers.ros.org/users/20658/pikaboo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that the idea behind the whole navigation stack is Indoor navigation where access to GPS is not possible.

If you want to use google maps I guess you could save a picture of the map and with some post processing make all buildings black and all roads white. But you will need a long range lidar (Velodyne lidar for example)

Or you could also just fix your phone on the robot and get the GPS estimated position combined with Google maps (there must be some API to use google maps from on your own program)

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0